# Entity Framework with Dataverse

Tags: c#, .net, api, entity-framework, dataverse

I was asked to create Web API built on top of Dataverse database.
I know that Dataverse already has its own API and web service to access data, but at some point in the future we may want to move from Dataverse to another DB, that's why decision was made to build API on top of existing Dataverse API.

I am not very experienced in building APIs, but my first though was to start using Entity Framework with Dataverse (as I am more familiar with EF than Dataverse API).

Do you have any experience in this field, I mean accessing data from Dataverse by using Entity Framework instead of provided services (REST API, OrgSvc)? Does it make sense at all or should I use existing services?

Comment: Using EF would require to use the `IOrganisationService` at some point - so that's really not an "either-or" proposition. The problem with the `OrgSvc` approach is that the .NET Core support so far is a bit sketchy - I've begun using the REST API more and more - seems easier, and often a lot faster, too - as long as it's available and works. You could definitely design a custom API of your own, and use the Dataverse REST API in the implementation so that you could swap it out if ever needed

Answer (score 2):

Just connect to the [TDS endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/dataverse-sql-query) and access Dataverse as if it were SQL Server.  I doubt that [Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) will work, so you'll probably need to hand-write your entities and/or SQL statements.

Note the TDS endpoint is read-only.

Comment: the TDS endpoint for Dataverse only allows READ operations, not a full CRUD

Answer (score 0):

We have been using MS Dynamics Dataverse for over a year now and really struggling to access the data using .net framework 4.7.2.

Our DevTeam even thought about purchasing the solution from CData (source: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dataverse-ado-codefirst.rst) but it comes with a huge price tag.

Microsoft says that the work for EF is in-progress. So let
s wait and see how long it will take: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/plan#dataverse-formerly-common-data-services